# How do you use ngrx in the APP_INITIALIZER of an Angular 2+ app?

Tags: angular, angular5, ngrx

Trying to use ngrx in my app and right away have found a problem.  I need to load some data on app initialization and would like to store it in my state store for all components to use.  However, the ngrx dispatcher is apparently using some async code and the data is not available in the store when the first route component is loaded.

Is there a way to get ngrx store to block the thread until it completes the storage operation so that the data is available when the app is loaded?

Comment: how do you load the data? can share the code sample

Answer (score 0):

From the article linked by @HisDivineShadow:

The factory (provided to Angular) can return a Promise. In that case the Angular-App stopps bootstrapping until the Promise is resolved.
To work with ngrx, the initialization method can resolve the Promise as soon as the ngrx-store is updated to ready state.

Example (app.module.ts):

```
...,
providers: [{
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: initApplication,
    deps: [Store]
    multi: true
}],
....

export function initApplication(store: Store): Function {
    return () => new Promise(resolve => {
        store.select(selectInitializationState)
            .pipe(
               takeWhile( state => !state.ready, true ),
               filter( config => state.ready ) )
            .subscribe( () => resolve(true) );
        store.dispatch(startInitializationAction());
    })
}
```